# Descriptive label for gantttitle

Tags: pgfgantt

I'm using pgfgantt within MikTeX (both latest version) running fine.
In my gantt diagramm I have three title-lines: First year, than month and beneath the project month.
I'd like to place the text `project month` in the last title line just aligned like the titles produced by `ganttbar`.

For better understanding here is a mwe (okay, the progress issues could further be removed)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,dotted,draw=none},%
                today=15,%
                today offset=.5,%
                today label=Heute,%
                progress=today,%
                bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
                progress label text={\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
                ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2012-5-1}{2015-4-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttbar{Arbeitspaket 1}{1}{4}\\
\ganttbar{Arbeitspaket 2}{3}{24}\\
\ganttbar{Arbeitspaket 3}{17}{36}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding result:

[image: typesetted mwe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange that this hasn't been answered before. I suppose you're done with that project by now, but perhaps you, or someone else, is interested in a solution anyways.

I'm not very familiar with `pgfgantt`, so this solution, while it does work, is not very elegant. Three modifications has been made to your code:

- Add a `tikzpicture` environment around the `pgfgantt` environment.
- Give the canvas a node name with `canvas/.append style={name=mycanvas}` added to the chart options.
- Place a new node with the text `project month` relative to the top left corner of the canvas node. This requires some trial and error to find an appropriate value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,dotted,draw=none},%
                today=15,%
                today offset=.5,%
                today label=Heute,%
                progress=today,%
                bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
                progress label text={\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%},
                canvas/.append style={name=mycanvas}
                ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2012-5-1}{2015-4-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttbar{Arbeitspaket 1}{1}{4}\\
\ganttbar{Arbeitspaket 2}{3}{24}\\
\ganttbar{Arbeitspaket 3}{17}{36}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\node [left] at ([yshift=-2.3cm]mycanvas.north west) {Project month};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently that feature is still missing. I couldn't find anything easier than this workaround 8 years later.